# Conditionally casting the input to a Typescript function

Tags: typescript

I am confused about the correct way to fix an error in the block of code below.

```
public static getByProps = (values: object | object[]) => {
        Array.isArray(values) ? (values = values) : (values = [values] as object[]);
        let keys = Object.keys(values);
        let dbArr = keys.map(key => `${Notes.tableName}.${key}`);
        values = values.map(value => keys.map(key => value[key]));
        return Notes.getQuery(builder => builder.whereIn(dbArr, values));
};
```

The input for this function should be either an object or an array of objects. If the function receives a single object, I convert that object to an array of objects with one element. I chose to do this because I don't have to worry about formatting when making calls from other parts of the code base.

Typescript throws error `TS2339: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'object | object[]'` for the line of code below.

```
values = values.map(value => keys.map(key => value[key]))
```

I understand that Typescript thinks values can be an object which wouldn't have the property map, but I am not exactly sure how to cast it, or how to properly restructure my code. Can anyone explain this problem to me?

Comment: Use a new variable. Reassigning parameters is ugly anyway. `const array = Array.isArray(values) ? values : [values];`

Comment: As to differentiating union types, see https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types

Answer (score 2):

Typescript is giving you a valid linting error, because your union type of `object | object[]` doesnt always have a method `map`. because in the case that its an object, it would not exist. Since you are reassigning on the same variable, it is expecting that the value follows the same convention. Thus is gives you an error.

What you should probably do is create a new variable within the scope of your function which can only be an array of objects.

```
public static getByProps = (inputValues: object | object[]) => {

        let values : object[] = Array.isArray(inputValues) ? inputValues :  [inputValues];
        let keys = Object.keys(values);
        let dbArr = keys.map(key => `${Notes.tableName}.${key}`);
        let valueKeyMap = values.map(value => keys.map(key => value[key]));
        return Notes.getQuery(builder => builder.whereIn(dbArr, valueKeyMap));
    };
```

Comment: I would like to add that reassigning a different type to "values" is going to end in tears. I suggest changing `values = values.map` to `const valueKeyArray = values.map`.

Comment: @Olian04 very good point... lol. i'll be honest and admit that I'd not even looked that far down into their code to see any other anti-patterns. I'll edit to include this.